# In vim, how can I write a line to top of buffer on open, and remove that line on save?

Tags: vim, flowtype, vim-plugin

I am using vim as my text editor for programming in react/javascript, and trying to use `flow` for static type checking. In my .flowconfig, I have `all=true`, meaning I would like to have flow type checking on all `.js` files without requiring a comment at the top of each file. I have the vim plugin `ale` setup to lint flow and give errors, and it works fine when I have the flow comment (`// @flow`) at the top of the file, but I would like this to work on every `.js` file without needing the comment at the top (as specified in my `.flowconfig`).

Afters spending some time tinkering with ale, I thought my best option may be to simply prepend the comment at the top of the file when a new buffer is opened, and then remove it before saving. Is there a way to do this in my `.vimrc` with an autocommand?

**Bonus:** *Extra brownie points if you can get this to work using only ale and not needing to add the flow comment to every file*

Comment: [See `:h g:ale_javascript_flow_use_respect_pragma`](https://github.com/w0rp/ale/blob/5addd3abefdbc828d92386e27dedfa79d39c5d9d/doc/ale-javascript.txt#L106)

Comment: @PeterRincker Wow I was hoping it would be this easy.. thank you!

Comment: I do not use flow so I am not sure exactly how this works with Ale. I would recommend you fix you problem and then post an answer to your own question so that others can see a proper solution